# Creating two y-axis chart with openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl

I'm trying to create a chart with two axes in openpyxl

```
# data is a sheet
# chart_data is a dataframe that's already been pasted onto the data sheet
# the first column of the dataframe is date (x-axis) and columns 2 and 3 are the two lines of the graph
chart = LineChart()
chart_data = Reference(data, min_col=2, max_col=3, min_row=1, max_row=len(chart_data))
chart.add_data(chart_data, titles_from_data=True)

labels = Reference(data, min_col=1, max_col=1, min_row=2, max_row=len(chart_data))

chart.title = 'Title'
chart.set_categories(labels)

chart.legend.position = 't'
chart.height = 20
chart.width = 25
chart.x_axis.tickLblPos = "low"
chart.x_axis.tickLblSkip = 30
chart.y_axis.number_format = '#,##0'

ws = wb['sheet_to_paste_chart']
ws.add_chart(chart, 'B24')
```

The y axes are actually the same data. But I want the left y-axis to be the y values / 1000 and the right y-axis to be the y values / 1 million.

They'll also be labeled "Thousands" and "Millions" respectively.

Comment: This is covered in the documentation: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/charts/secondary.html

Comment: It didn't work for me. I'm not combining two different graphs, I'm combining the same line graphs using the same data but they just scale their y axes differently.

Comment: If you want two y-axes you need two charts, that's how it works.